# can we use Framework 7 design with ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, html-framework-7

I'm working on a ReactNative app and the designer sent me a design made with **Framework 7** is there is a way to use this design inside **ReactNative** ?

Comment: I think it's hard. `Framework 7` is a web app, `react native` runs with native controls